# Equivalent container to java.util.HashMap but without value feild

Tags: java, containers

I need a java container similar to HashMap that stores only objects (instead of key-value pairs) indexed by hash code. What is such a container called? Is there a java implementation of it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you're looking for a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table

Note that an HashSet doesn't allow duplicates.